# how to install dependencies or use composer at all in windows

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I've installed composer via windows installer, and set the correct path  variables for php to wamp's php, now I created a composer.json( and later .phar) file

and attempt to install dependencies listed there

```
{
"name": "phpunit/php-unit",
"require": {
    "php": ">5.4.12",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.28"
}
}
```

this comes out of almost every command, including

```
php composer.phar install
php composer.json install
```

i did ran this in windows cmd so im not sure if that affects anything.

Comment: On the command line when you type `php composer.phar`, does it return anything? if not, then there might be something wrong with the installation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: actually there is a Windows installer on the Composer [download page](http://getcomposer.org/download/) that will install Composer globally, so you won't need any `composer.phar` anymore. Install it from [here](http://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe), and then just run "composer install" from the directory where you have your `composer.json`.

*(original answer below)*

I didn't test this myself, but I think it's how it should work :

Download the `composer.phar` and put it in the same directory as your `composer.json`.

`cd` into the directory where you have your `composer.json` :

> cd some\directory

Finally, run the composer :

> php composer.phar install

Comment: @user2167582 So if you installed it, then open a cmd window, go into your working directory and type "composer install", and it should work.

Answer (score 18):

**For very Beginner Windows Users**

1. Download the installer for windows from [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
2. Check the installation by executing `composer` command at command prompt
3. Now, create the `composer.json` file at the same level where you have `Vendor` directory (not inside `Vendor`).
4. Move to the directory where you have `composer.json` with the command prompt and run the following command:

   ```
   composer install
   ```
5. It will show messages like 'packages are downloaded' and 'autoload.php file created'. (Check your `/app/Vendor/` directory)
6. Now insert this code at the beginning of `/app/config/core.php`:

   ```
   require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';
   ```

The code above will load all the classes automatically.

Hope this helps for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem for a long time  but with a simple mistake
Okay First need to enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` on your php.ini
and if it does not exist , so enable or add in to end of file
second step go to this directory :

```
C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Composer
```

And paste your composer.json to here , make a folder to sure and name it that "vendor" , then enable or run your PHP server and run **cmd** as administrator and type this

```
composer install
```

Enjoy It